# PHP Count Function Like On Excel

Tags: php, mysql

Need help to do excel function in PHP + Mysql,

I have an excel data that contain coloumn and row like this:

| Transaction | Debit | Credit | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Transaction 1 | 1000 | 0 | 1000 |
| Transaction 2 | 500 | 0 | 1500 |
| Transaction 3 | 0 | 700 | 800 |

The **balance** row formula is
**Debit - Credit + Balance (from the upper transaction)**

the excel example is here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mv3lIS9TenYpGyblSoPXrN26c7sMI4E_iJ51yMN-K8A/edit?usp=sharing

I save the Transaction, Debit, Credit data in Mysql.

I call the data on PHP using foreach

foreach($x as $result)
{

$result['transaction'];

$result['debit'];

$result['credit'];

}

**My Question is:**

How to make php + mysql function to make balance count like on excel.

thank you

Comment: This can be done with window function in SQL. `select t.*, sum(debit-credit) over (rows UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) balance from transactions t order by transaction`. And DB Fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ee6212cfc27c508aeb9cfa2f946ff816

Answer (score 0):

You can just keep another variable ($balanceAmount, say) and update it in your loop. You haven't provided exactly how you're displaying this information (and I assume you're not trying to store this balance amount in the DB, only the credit and debit amounts), but something like the following should work for you if I understand the question correctly:

```
$balanceAmount = 0; // or whatever the initial balance amount is

foreach($x as $result)
{
  $balanceAmount += $result['debit'];
  $balanceAmount -= $result['credit'];

  //
  // ...do other stuff here to display the data for each cell in the current row...
  //
}
```